# Entity связь один ко многим

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Суть программы в том, что она создаёт базу данных и добавляет в неё таблицы (с этим она справляется) и выводит в консоль Название книги и её Автора через свойство library в классе Books, за счёт связи один ко многим.

```
internal class Books
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int AuthorsID { get; set; }
            public virtual Library library{ get; set; }
        }

internal class Library
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Style { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }

internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("DbConnectionString")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }

using(var context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var author = new Library()
                {
                    Name = "Gogol",
                    Style = "Horror"
                };
                

                var author2 = new Library()
                {
                    Name = "Puskkin"
                };
                context.Libraries.Add(author);
                context.Libraries.Add(author2);
                context.SaveChanges();

                var books = new List<Books>()
                {
                    new Books() { Name = "Viy", AuthorsID = author.Id},
                    new Books() { Name ="Evgeniy Onegin", AuthorsID = author2.Id}
                };
                context.Books.AddRange(books);
                context.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var book in books) {


                    Console.WriteLine($" Book name = {book.Name}, Authors name = {book.library.Name}");}
```

Почему свойство `library` в строке `{book.library.Name}`  возвращает значение Null. Из за этого вылезает исключение NRE и соответственно ничего не выводится.

P.s - Извиняюсь за повторный вопрос.

Comment: вопросы дубликаты тут запрещены, так как ваш предыдущий вопрос всё ещё активен, я и остальные пользователи постараемся вам помочь с ним